# Would the Unearthed Arcana Revived Rogue subclass have its hit point maximum reduced in Tomb of Annihilation?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, unearthed-arcana, hit-points, tomb-of-annihilation

I've been playing Tomb of Annihilation lately and asked my DM for his thoughts on using Unearthed Arcana material. He said he was cool with it which got me thinking. I've been interested in trying out [the Revived Rogue subclass](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-RuneSwarmRevived.pdf#page=4), but then I realized ToA has the Death Curse as the big driving plot point.

> Any humanoid on the planet that has been brought back from the dead begins to waste away. Its hit point maximum is reduced by 20 (1 for each day the Soulmonger has been active) and decreases by 1 every midnight until the Soulmonger is destroyed. If a humanoid’s hit point maximum drops to 0, it dies. Traveling to another world or plane does nothing to halt the wasting effect once it has begun.

I mentioned this in the chat but not everyone seemed convinced that the Revived Rogue would be considered *revived* for the sake of the death curse reducing its HP max.  One person even said that the rogue could have just been brought back to life before the Soulmonger was activated which it would have had to have been regardless as nobody can be resurrected anyway once it activates and Syndra even mentions that she died before saying

> “I was an adventurer years ago. I died once and was raised from the dead. I have since closed the door on that stage of my life.”

The subclass specifically mentions in its description

> You’ve had a soul-shaking realization: you’ve been dead before, yet somehow you are alive again.

and

> You might have convinced a deity to let you return to the Material Plane, perhaps you signed a deal with a fiend, or maybe you used an artifact that revived you.

So I ask here; **Is the Revived Rogue subclass considered to have been raised from the dead for the sake of the Death Curse in Tomb of Annihilation?**

*Note: I am primarily looking for a RAW answer but you are welcome to include how you would rule as well.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Your hp maximum is probably reduced

> Any humanoid on the planet that has been brought back from the dead...

and

> ...you’ve been dead before, yet somehow you are alive again.

Are pretty clear.  You definitely lose hp if you fulfill line one.  The only reason I say probably in the header instead of definitely is because you aren't necessarily humanoid or 'on the planet'; centaurs, for example, are fey, and *polymorph* et al can also let you dodge the Soulmonger's midnight trigger.

Answer (score 7):

### There's Ambiguity Here

Enough that you could make an argument to a DM, at any rate.

> This life   isn’t your  first;  it  might   not even    be  your    second. Your    past    life,   or  lives,  are unclear to  you,    but you know    that    you passed  through the gates   of  death.

You know what else has passed through the gates of death? Angels, demons, devils... extraplanar entities of all kinds (not all of them, but many) were once alive, but were remade into something else after they died.

You haven't been revived. Heck, you might not have even been reincarnated. Your soul has been recycled, yes, but what you've been made into is undeniably something *other*- both mentally and physically, as we'll see- than what you were before, which puts you closer to an angel or devil (or even undead) in construction than the person you once were.

> You   don’t   need    to  eat,    drink,  or  breathe.
>
> You   don’t   need    to  sleep.

These don't sound like you've been "revived" at all.

> You   have    learned to  unleash bolts   of  necrotic    energy from within  your    revived body.

But this sure does.

> [W]henever    you have    0   hit points  and are healed  or  stabilized, you can change  any of  your    personal    characteristics:    personality trait,  ideal,  bond,   or  flaw.

You certainly haven't been revived by the traditional sense of the word. More like... recycled.

> you   are one of  death’s representatives among   the living.

Comment: A good argument, I don't think reincarnation counts as being "brought back from the dead", there doesn't seem to be any indication that a Revived was 'brought back', other than the ominous archetype name.